# JCodec Picture to BufferedImage

Tags: bufferedimage, jcodec

I am new to JCodec, but I am attempting to convert a JCodec Picture to a BufferedImage. Unfortunately, the methods to do so in JCodec have been deprecated, save for those methods converting a Picture to a Picture8Bit. However, I haven't found a JCodec method for the conversion of a Picture to a Picture8Bit.

Comment: Actually, the whole `Picture` class is deprecated, and telling you to use `Picture8Bit` instead. So, you should probably not have used `Picture` in the first place.

Comment: The getNativeFrame() only will return a Picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes `FrameGrab` and `Picture` are all deprecated, that is why also all methods using `Picture` is deprecated in `AWTUtil`.

Instead, use the class `FrameGrab8Bit`, where the `getNativeFrame()` method will return a `Picture8Bit`. Then you can easily use all the non-deprecated methods of `AWTUtil`.

Comment: I hadn't realized the download of JCodec hadn't included `FrameGrab8Bit`

Answer (score 2):

Among the standard distribution there are submodules of JCodec like **javase** and **android**. These modules contain helper classes to convert to BufferedImages:

```
AWTUtil.toBufferedImage(Picture)
```

Latest versions (8/2017):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec-javase</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcodec-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```